# Why would a public property on a class not be accessible when an instance is passed as an Input to an Angular component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

(The following code extract illustrates a problem in more complex code where a public method is reported as "not defined")

I have defined a class Organisation with a field/variable organisationName and a public property get OrganisationName()

```
export class Organisation {
  organisationName = '';

  public get OrganisationName(): string {
    return this.organisationName;
  }
}
```

I can instantiate this, set the organisationName and access the property OrganisationName

```
let x = new Organisation();
x.organisationName = 'New Org';
console.log('X Field', x.organisationName);
console.log('X Property', x.OrganisationName);
```

[image]

However if I pass an instance of an Organisation to an Angular component, the property is returning undefined

```
export class OrganisationEditComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() organisation = new Organisation();
```

In ngOnInit because the property is undefined I've also tried creating another instance based on the Input and accessing OrganisationName(). That too gives undefined

```
let y = this.organisation as Organisation;
console.log('y Field', y.organisationName);
console.log('y Property', y.OrganisationName);
```

[image]

What do I need to do to be able to access the property of the Organisation instance passed into the Angular component as an Input()?

I've also tried defining the organisation Input as follows:

```
@Input() organisation!: Organisation;
```

This makes no difference.

---

UPDATE

The issue arises from the fact that I'm populating the data from an API. If the property doesn't exist in the data returned then the method is not accessible in the Angular application even though it is defined there. If I add the property to the API data, then this is what is displayed, not whatever is returned from the class defined in Angular.

Stackblitz simulation here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-jqzlfj?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: I would probably assume you should rename your getter to match the variable name exactly. Try that and see if it works

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that doesn't work - VSCode/TypeScript complains this is a duplicate identifier

Comment: That's because you want to do it like this: `class foo {
    private _bar: boolean = false;
    get bar(): boolean {
        return this._bar;
    }
    set bar(value: boolean) {
        this._bar = value;
    }
}`

Comment: you sure you don't want "import" instead of "@Input" (which would come from the DOM) here?

Comment: This line: `let y = this.organisation as Organisation;`, does not magically convert that object to an `Organisation` type.

Comment: @Silvermind that was an attempt to fix this up that didn't work

Comment: Your added information about the data coming straight from the API is exactly my point.

Comment: Thanks @Silvermind but what's the way round this? Is there an easy way to cast the json to the javascript class and make the getter accessible?

Comment: I've found the answer - I need to use Object.assign - I've updated the Stackblitz example

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

After looking at your Stackblitz, it's clear what the issue really is.

Your `Organisation` is a class, so when creating a new class, you should always use the `new` keyword. You are creating an anonymous object and casting is as the type (remember that Javascript has no knowledge of types). The only reason that it is working with the `Object.assign` line is because `this.organisation` was created using `new` and `Object.assign` uses that original object to create the new object from. Simply changing your anonymous objects to ones that are actual classes solves the problem.

```
    var org1 = new Organisation();
    org1.organisationName = 'Smith & Co';
    org1.id = 492;
    this.organisations.push(org1);
    var org2 = new Organisation();
    org2.organisationName = 'Jonas Brothers';
    org2.id = 47;
    this.organisations.push(org2);
    var org3 = new Organisation();
    org3.organisationName = 'Browns Ltd';
    org3.id = 1033;
    this.organisations.push(org3);

    // Display a selected organisation in app-organisation component
    // organisation is bound to app-organisation in the template above

    this.organisation = this.organisations[2]; // displayName IS accessible
```

So, in your return from your API, you will need to map all the objects to your class using the `new` keyword. You can add a constructor with the parameters you need so that you don't have to set every property on a single line.

It's also worth mentioning, I wouldn't recommend using classes this way to just get your display name. I would skip mapping the objects entirely and just use an interface or type, then get your display name using a custom angular pipe.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

The problem may be that you are setting a default value to the input property...

```
export class OrganisationEditComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() organisation = new Organisation();
```

Setting a default value might cause unexpected behavior if you are really expecting the value to be set from outside the component. When the `OnInit` fires, it's possible you might not have the value from the outside and you still have the default value. That really depends on the parent components, which you didn't include in the question.

I would recommend that you do something like this...

```
export class OrganisationEditComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() organisation: Organisation | undefined;
```

Then later in your code, you will be forced to make sure the the `organisation` input has been set before you try accessing it or it's members.

Doing this is typically a bad idea...

```
@Input() organisation!: Organisation;
```

Because, the `!` only tells the Typescript compiler to "pretend" that the property will never be `null` or `undefined`. It doesn't actually do anything at runtime. This can cause bugs if the value is ever `null` or `undefined` at runtime. Use `!` with extreme caution.

Side note:

I wouldn't create classes the way you show. There are a few issues with the way you have your Organisation class. I recommend the following...

- Always use camel casing
- Make backing properties private and use a setter of the properties have the same name and meaning.
- OR change the name of the getter to represent the meaning better (for example if you need to transform the value)

```
export class Organisation {
  private _organisationName = '';

  public get organisationName(): string {
    return this._organisationName;
  }

  public set organisationName(value: string) {
    this._organisationName = value;
  }

  // Example to illustrate a single getter and changing the name
  public get displayName(): string {
    return `Your organisation: ${this._organisationName}`;
  }
}
```

Comment: If the @Input() organisation is not initialised (to a new instance) I get "property has no initialiser and is not definitely assigned in the constructor". If I allow undefined I then  need to do type checking or use the elvis operator to check for null. In the original code that added a lot of "clutter".

Comment: I've created a Stackblitz without using private backing variable in the model and using a "new" initialiser on the @Input() and this works! I'm not sure if this is because Stackblitz in now Angular 16 and I'm still on 15, or whether I've missed an important detail in the original code? https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-z79qqy?file=src%2Fmain.ts Appreciate your time looking at this.

Comment: There's obviously something else I've done wrong in the original code. I've tried and failed to replicate the issue in a new Angular 15 project.

Comment: Update added above with reproduction of issue in Stackblitz

Answer (score -1):

Answering my own question, but not accepting it as I don't fully understand the javascript (coming from a strongly typed world)

Comment from @Silvermind:
This line: let y = this.organisation as Organisation;, does not magically convert that object to an Organisation type

The answer is to use Object.assign

I've updated the Stackblitz example - https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-jqzlfj?file=src%2Fmain.ts

main.ts line 40

```
// this.organisation = this.organisations[2]; // displayName is not accessible
Object.assign(this.organisation, this.organisations[2]); // displayName is accessible
```

Simple assignment does not give me an instance of the type expected. Is this by design or a limitation of javascript?